# Help with checking solution to PDE IVBP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

I need help checking my solution to a PDE. The book I am using is PDE for Scientists and Engineers(exponentially increasing functions are excluded) and the chapter is on *Laplace transform*. Furthermore, the Laplace transform is with respect to time. Here is the problem:

PDE: $$u_t = u_{xx}$$

BC: $$u(0,t) = sin(t)$$

IC: $$u(x, 0) = 0$$

Here is my work:

$$\mathcal{L}[u_t] = \mathcal{L}[u_{xx}]$$
$$sU(x,s)-u(x,0) = \frac{d^2 U}{dx^2} = sU$$

Assuming that the $U = e^{rx}$,

$$\frac{d^2U}{dx^2} = r^2e^{rx} = sU = se^{rx}$$
$$r^2 = s$$
$$r = \pm \sqrt{s}$$
Which leads to a general solution of, 
$$U = c_1e^{x\sqrt{s}} + c_2e^{-x\sqrt{s}}$$

Converting the BC,
$$\mathcal{L}[u(0,t)] = \mathcal{L}[sin(t)] = \frac{1}{s^2+1}$$
$$U(0) = \frac{1}{s^2+1} = c_1+c_2$$
$$\frac{1}{s^2+1} = \frac{A}{s+i}+ \frac{B}{s-i} = \frac{A(s-i)+B(s+i)}{s^2+1}$$
Noticing that $i$ appears on one side and not the other,($A=B$) then
$$As-Ai +Bs+Bi = 1 = 2As$$
$$A = \frac{1}{2s}$$
$$c_1 + c_2 = \frac{A}{s+i}+ \frac{B}{s-i}= \frac{1}{2s(s+i)}+\frac{1}{2s(s-i)}$$

$$U = \frac{1}{2s(s+i)}e^{x\sqrt{s}}+\frac{1}{2s(s-i)}e^{-x\sqrt{s}}$$
Here I eliminate the exponentially increasing solution leading to, 
$$U = \frac{1}{2s(s-i)}e^{-x\sqrt{s}}$$

Unfortunately I do not have a way to apply the Laplace transform, so what I did next, which doesn't make much sense to me, was to drop the exponentially increasing solution before applying the BC.
Thus the work here goes as follows
$$U = ce^{-x\sqrt{s}}$$ 
Applying BC's,

$$U(0) = \frac{1}{s^2+1} = c$$
$$U = \frac{s}{s} \frac{1}{s^2+1}e^{-x\sqrt{s}} = \frac{s}{s^2+1} \frac{e^{-x\sqrt{s}}}{s}$$
Here I use the convolution property of transforms, 
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}[f*g] = \mathcal{L^{-1}}[f] \mathcal{L^{-1}}[g]$$
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\left[\frac{s}{s^2+1}\right] \mathcal{L^{-1}} \left[ \frac{e^{-x\sqrt{s}}}{s} \right]$$
$$[cos(t)]*\left[ erfc \left(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{t}}\right) \right]$$
Note I am not required to simplify a convolution.

Comment: `which doesn't make much sense to me, was to drop the exponentially increasing solution` you need to do this as solution should be bounded. I  solved similar PDE [workaround-for-dsolve-in-v-12-when-it-gives-undefined-as-solution-to-1d-heat-pde](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201678/workaround-for-dsolve-in-v-12-when-it-gives-undefined-as-solution-to-1d-heat-pde)

Comment: As far as I understand, the only way to say that a Coefficient is zero is by way of Boundary Conditions.

Comment: Also the answer does not match that which I found at the end of the book. I obtained the transforms from the book. All in all I was hoping for someone to spot some kind of hole in my logic or something.

Comment: You did not say what is the domain. This is important to make it clear. I assume $0<x<\infty$ and$t>0$?

Comment: Yes your limits are correct. As far as the answer goes, I am not sure why they are different.

Comment: my answer is correct. I verified it using Maple. Maple is not wrong :)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Do you think my answer is incorrect? The book lacks the transform for $e^{-x\sqrt{\frac{s}{k}}}$

Comment: You can find this transform for $e^{-x\sqrt{...}}$ in tables/Wikepdia or using Wolfram alpha it should know it. I am not sure if your final answer is correct or not, but should be to verify with some work. (not sure why you have $\cos(t)$ in there.

Comment: The reason is that I have erfc in the tables. However erfc has an s in the denominator. So I multiplied the whole thing by s/s. I took the s for the denominator. But I left the s in the numerator for the sine transform. This simply becomes the cosine transform. 

As for why I didn't look it up, I try to only use the information given by the book.